# pm2: loading processes.json without automatically starting apps

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have got `pm2` installed locally (not running as a daemon). No applications are loaded yet:

```
$ pm2 status
┌────────────────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name           │ id │ mode    │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory       │ watching │
└────────────────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──────────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

Now, suppose I am starting an application using a `process.json` file (example [here](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/examples/process.json)). In this situation, the command `pm2 start process.json` does the following:

1. Loads the application data, such that pm2 is aware of it
2. Starts the application

Here is the output:

```
$ pm2 start process.json
...
$ pm2 status
┌────────────────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name           │ id │ mode    │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory       │ watching │
├────────────────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──────────────┼──────────┤
│ hapiprocess        │ 0  │ cluster │ 3749 │ online │ 1       │ 0s     │  10.090 MB   │ disabled │
└────────────────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──────────────┴──────────┘
```

I would like however to first "load" the application data into pm2, without automatically starting it; the startup would be done later using `pm2 start <application-name>`.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

As I know, pm2 doesn't support that feature only loading, but you can it by executing start and stop in a row. just following command,

```
$ pm2 start <application-name> && pm2 stop <application-name>
```

Comment: `pm2 start; pm2 stop all` or  `pm2 start && pm2 stop all` from the directory which has the `ecosystem.config.js` file.